# How to manually set access tokens on OAuthRestTemplate, spring-security-oauth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to call an api that uses Oauth 1a using `OAuthRestTemplate` from spring-security-oauth.

I saw that most of the examples set the consumer key and secret and then let the library get the access tokens.
I have the token and the token secret (which do not expire) and I want to set them on the OAuthRestTemplate and make calls, without going through the authentication flow.

Is that possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK that's not possible (it is on the OAuth2 side but OAuth1 never got as much love). Contributions gratefully accepted.

Comment: Can you please point me to how this is done with OAuth2?  I'm searching for that now and ended up here.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, though a bit hacky. Example code below:

```
    // Assume you have a preconfigured RestTemplate
    OAuthRestTemplate template = new OAuthRestTemplate(resource);

    OAuthConsumerToken accessToken = new OAuthConsumerToken();
    accessToken.setAccessToken(true);
    accessToken.setResourceId(template.getResource().getId());
    accessToken.setValue(ACCESS_TOKEN);

    OAuthSecurityContextImpl securityContext = new OAuthSecurityContextImpl();
    securityContext.setAccessTokens(new HashMap<>());
    securityContext.getAccessTokens().put(accessToken.getResourceId(), accessToken);

    OAuthSecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
```

Ideally, you should check whether an existing security context exists, and add the token to the map if it's not already present.

Comment: @DaveSyer - Am I right to assume that the `OAuthSecurityContextHolder` behaves similarly to `SecurityContextHolder` in that any mechanism is free to write into this?